# Need audible time reminder, please help me to get it right?

Tags: bash, sound, cron

Often I totally get zoned in to what I'm doing & totally lose track of the time.
A little reminder that time has passed is all I need to be able to stay on track, so:

I have espeak & this line works very well with it in the CLI:

```
date +"%I-%M"|espeak -v mb-us1 -s120
```

Wanting this reminder at the hour & 1/2 hour, I made the crontab lines thusly:

```
0 0,1,2,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23 *  *  *  sh  /root/.saytime.sh
```

And:

```
*/30 0,1,2,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23  *  *  *  sh  /root/.saytime.sh
```

Also having made .saytime.sh thusly & made it executable:

```
#!/bin/bash
date +"%I-%M"|espeak -v mb-us1 -s120
```

And according to the syslog, the script gets run, but no sounds are made. How can I fix this?